# How to write div/box on other frame in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a frameset and 2 frames.

Now, What i want is while clicking on an image/button i have to open a box/div with some text but this box/div is coming over other frame, so i am not able to see this box/div.

I tried using **"z-index"** but its not working,

Below is the sample code,

**Main_File.html**

```
<head>
<frameset row="53px,*">
<frame src="frame1.html">
<frame src="frame2.html">
</frameset>
</head>
```

**End Of Main_File.html.**

**frame1.html**

```
<html>
    <style>
    #hiddenDiv
    {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function popupFunc()
    {
    var temp=document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
    temp.style.display='block';
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="sampleDiv" style="height:53px;width:99%;position:absolute;">
    <img src="someImage.jpg" onclick="popupFunc()" />
    </div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv" style="top:60px;">
    Some Text
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in above code,

When i click on hidden button it should open a div over other frame but its not happening,
Can any body help?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. `popFunc()` is not defined but `popupFunc()` is. Changing this fixes it. But the linked answer does have a nicer approach to this request.

Comment: @jaunt: Thanks, but i do not want to change from frameset to iframe,
how to do the same in frameset?

Comment: Just change `onclick="popFunc()"` to `onclick="popupFunc()"` fixes when I test it, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @jaunt : Thanks, but its just a typing mistake, this is just a sample code.

Comment: Oh my bad, misunderstood: the duplicate is your answer for this then.